# Angular 2 - Implement Factory Pattern

Tags: angular, design-patterns, angular2-template, factory-pattern

I am a newbie in Angular2. I want to implement Factory design pattern using Angular2,I have seen some examples for typescript supporting Factory pattern.
How do we define the templates if the requirement is to have some common fields in one html and additional fields in another html.

eg: In motor vehicles, we have different categories like Car, bus , truck etc . Motor vehicle will have own set of elements(Tyre,window) and functionalities which will be common for different categories and some will be specific to that category. So, need to know how will we design our template so that we can reuse the common elements for all vehicle types and can have their own specific functionalities or elements.

Also I want to understand If there is any configuration available to extract the specific modules/features while building the app?

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.